# How to convert union type of strings to union type of objects?

Tags: typescript, types, type-inference

I'm finding a way to convert union of strings

```js
type Letters = 'a'|'b'|'c'|'d';
```

to union of objects.

```js
type ObjectsMadeOfLetters = { prop: 'a' }|{ prop: 'b'}|{ prop: 'c' }|{ prop: 'd' };
```

Does anybody knows some typescript formula for this?

Okay, at the same time of posting this question I tried one solution, pretty enough.

```js
type ObjectsMadeOfLetters = Letters extends infer U ? U extends string ? { prop: U } : never : never;
```

Result is:

```js
type ObjectsMadeOfLetters = {
    prop: 'a';
} | {
    prop: 'b';
} | {
    prop: 'c';
} | {
    prop: 'd';
}
```

Are there more methods to do this in typescript?

Comment: Does this one work? `type Generate<T> = T extends T ? { prop: T } : never;` `type ObjectsMadeOfLetters = Generate<Letters>;`

Comment: @wonderflame Can you explain *why* does this work?

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine it's called [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)

Comment: Since it's strings, you could also use mapped types: `type Generate<T extends string> = { [K in T]: { prop: K } }[T];`

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
type ObjectsMadeOfLetters = {prop: Letters};
```

There's no real difference between a union of object types each with a single-value property, and a single object type with a multi-value union property.